# how to use AngularJS value as parameter in function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass an ID value once the button is clicked. 
but gives me this error: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzlDf.png)

What is the correct way of using: `ng-click="passID({{x.id}})"` ?

```
<table id="Content"  ng-repeat="x in images | limitTo:3">
<tr>
    <td class="one">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="contImage" ng-src="{{x.image}}" ng-alt="{{x.name}}" /></td>
            <td class="textAlign">{{x.name}} <button class="viewDetails" ng-click="passID({{x.id}})" type="button">VIEW DETAILS</button></td>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="two">{{x.size}}</td>
    <td class="one">{{x.storage}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just without {{}}:

```
ng-click="passID(x.id)"
```

Comment: ahaha thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 1):

correct way of using it is: `ng-click="passID(x.id)"`

You don't need to use interpolation: {{}}.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

`ng-click="passID(x.id)"`

instead of `ng-click="passID({{x.id}})"`

Because `ng-click` is an Angular directive it can understand the expression, as the element is inside the `ng-repeat` directive you can directly access the object specified in the `ng-repeat`